# Building a custom lock screen (and screensaver) for Win7 and above

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-10-desktop

I have a client that uses Windows desktop computers that are "always on," and which are accessed by multiple users, who interact with the same program instances. (For the sake of simplicity, imagine a proprietary sudoku game that does not support saving and several people solving the sudoku, one at a time.) Logging on and off is not an option, as this would terminate running applications. No, we can't do anything about this setup, so there is no point in coming up with a better solution. This is a hard client requirement.

In order to improve security (who was using the computer at a given time), they would like to implement their own "locking" mechanism. The screen should auto-lock after a given time (10 minutes or so), like a screen saver. This "lock screen" should also replace the built-in Windows lock screen, so you need to be able to activate it using `Win+L` etc.
It should also be semi-transparent (I hope we won't need DirectX or other fancy stuff for this).

To "unlock" the screen, you need to enter your active directory information (domain/username/password), which will written to a log file. As we don't actually want to change the logged on user, I guess a custom credentials provider is not what we are looking for.

From my research, it looks like we'll need to do is disable the built-in Windows lock screen in the registry and write a custom screensaver that would double as the lock screen. With the built-in lock screen disabled, a low-level global keyboard hook should be able to capture `Win+L`, right? From that keyboard hook, we could start the screensaver.

This stuff needs to work on machines running Windows 7 and above.
I feel most comfortable developing in C#, but C++ is fine, too.

Do you see any potential pitfalls with this approach?
Any better idea how to build this?

Comment: This isn't going to improve security.

Comment: "*Logging on and off is not an option, as this would terminate running applications*" - you can have multiple users logged in at the same time without terminating anything.  Of course, if you want multiple users to share applications, but only have one user active at a time, I think it is better to store shared/common data in a background service, and then create user apps to interact with that service. Then it won't matter if users logout or not, since the data will be preserved between login sessions.

Comment: Not sure if hooks lets you eat Win+L anymore.

Comment: Why is it so difficult to understand that this is a client requirement? They want to run a single-user application in a multiuser environment. I don't understand why they don't let it run on a terminal server and have users connect using RDP or such. But a large organization like this won't suddenly turn things around because some random developer tells them to remodel their whole infrastructure. Your well-intended alternative suggestions will go unheard, I have zero influence on these decisions. I understand where you're coming from, but it's a waste of your and my time.

Comment: I would hope that the system would regard any attempt to hijack the lock screen as being malware and block it. I certainly don't want my OS to allow software to do that. You might have been given a hard requirement but I would expect that you can't meet it.

Comment: Turning off the lock screen through the registry lets you catch `Win+L` via a low-level keyboard hook without issues, I've just verified that. I'd implement the rest as a screensaver and have `Win+L` simply fire that up. Certainly a screensaver would not be regarded as malware.